# TEI Documents to HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, tei

I've problems with some old documents encoded in TEI and I need to read these documents and print their content into a webpage (then HTML format).
Does there exists some classes or some tools userful in php to convert these files (I'm new with the TEI format) in a readable content?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Comment: The problem is that i don't have found nothing about php in TEI. I've only found an online tool (OxGarage) that convert files in PDF or other format bad and I've tried convert the file using DOM but some field are delimiter for example for a page and isn't a container then is maybe impossible or very difficult use this method. I need only a decoder that I've seen exist but i don't know where find it.

Comment: Does it really need to be PHP or do you have some other technologies at hand? If this is just about transformation, you could also try opening the files with Oxygen XML Editor and use the visualization there, or just use some CSS to display it in the browser. Can you give an example? And what do you mean by "decoder"? Sounds like TEI was an encrypted format. So, maybe you can limit your question to some programming related problem.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are looking for some classes in PHP to work with TEI and to transform TEI into HTML. You require an XSLT processor to do that. There is [PHP: XSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) which supports XSLT 1.0, which is ok for a start. It does not support TEI natively by itself, but you would have to write your own XSL to transform TEI elements into HTML elements. This is probably not the answer you were hoping for. Due to the complexity of TEI and all its modules it is difficult to invent general tools to create HTML from any TEI document, and you did not specify what the subject of your documents is. However, you can trigger transformation with PHP, and very probably you can adopt some XSL files from the resources available on http://www.tei-c.org. I hope this helps.